# Create a href link in select query statement using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to know it's possible to Create a href link in select query statement using mysql.

```
select '<a href=$site_URL/index.php?module=xxxxxx&view=Detail&record=a.mcaid>a.mcaid</a>' as dba,account_number as `account number` ,rate as split, CAST((-total_amount)/100 as DECIMAL(10,2)) as `total amount`, CAST((-withdrawal_amount)/100 as DECIMAL(10,2)) as `withdrawal amount`,  DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%m-%d-%Y') as `start date`,concat(name,'  ' ,a.mcaid) as mca  from fdr_me_daily_activity inner join vtiger_mcacf a on cf_1440=account_number  inner join vtiger_mca b
on b.mcaid=a.mcaid INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity on a.mcaid=vtiger_crmentity.crmid where vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 order by start_date desc  limit  0 , 50"
```

so this is my query, i want to pass the selected column in to the href link

```
<a href=$site_URL/index.php?module=xxxxxx&view=Detail&record=a.mcaid>**a.mcaid**</a> ;
```

**a.mcaid** - i can't able to pass the column into the href. so please can you help me.

I don't want to use php.

Regards,
Nandhagopal J

Comment: use a concat for this

Comment: Thanks chiraj.. I used concat and the issue was solved

Comment: accept my answer , so it can help to others in future and it helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Concat for joining the value.

```
select CONCAT('<a href=$site_URL/index.php?module=xxxxxx&view=Detail&record=a.mcaid>',a.mcaid,'</a>') as dba,account_number as `account number` ,rate as split, CAST((-total_amount)/100 as DECIMAL(10,2)) as `total amount`, CAST((-withdrawal_amount)/100 as DECIMAL(10,2)) as `withdrawal amount`,  DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%m-%d-%Y') as `start date`,concat(name,'  ' ,a.mcaid) as mca  from fdr_me_daily_activity inner join vtiger_mcacf a on cf_1440=account_number  inner join vtiger_mca b
on b.mcaid=a.mcaid INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity on a.mcaid=vtiger_crmentity.crmid where vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 order by start_date desc  limit  0 , 50"
```

I hope this is work for you.